# Best way to send & receive a color array over websockets

Tags: javascript, c++, c

I need to control lots of leds (for fun.. not work).

The [UI](http://jsfiddle.net/dgws3usa/5/) is written in javascript and will send data (a color array) approximatively 60 times per second.

The led driver is a microcontroller ([ESP8266](https://www.adafruit.com/images/product-files/2471/0A-ESP8266__Datasheet__EN_v4.3.pdf)) that is programmed in c++ using the [websocket library](https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets) with the arduino IDE

The leds are Addressable and controlled over a single pin. More about the data transmission btw led & microcontroller can be read in [this](https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812B.pdf) datasheet. But I'm using a simplified [library](https://github.com/JoDaNl/esp8266_ws2812_i2s) that drives those using [i2s](https://web.archive.org/web/20060702004954/http://www.semiconductors.philips.com/acrobat_download/various/I2SBUS.pdf) and so DMA to leave the CPU out.

At the moment I'm sending one color to the first led. the color is converted into a hex string to save space.

**Client**

```
//javascript
websocket.send('#ff0000');
```

**Server**

```
//c++
if(payload[0]=='#'){
 uint32_t rgb = (uint32_t) strtol((const char *) &payload[1], NULL, 16);
 pixels[1].R=((rgb >> 16) & 0xFF);
 pixels[1].G=((rgb >> 8) & 0xFF);
 pixels[1].B=((rgb >> 0) & 0xFF);
}
```

My first guess was to send a "hex" like string and then split it

```
"#ff0000ff0000ff0000"
//or
"#ff0000#ff0000#ff0000"
```

but I went to the chat and gathered some more info about this problem. People suggested me to use binary or ascii. That is somehow hard for me so i would need some examples. Especially for c++ part. I'm not even sure if the websocket lib is able to handle ascii or binary properly and then reconvert it back to numbers.

**The problem:**

The microcontroller has various limitations.Especially memory, also transmission speed and the time it takes to convert the data.
**The final color array should be small in bytes & easy to reconvert to rgb values.**

**What's the proper way to send and receive a color array ?**

---

The choice of the various libraries is long research:

- Arduino IDE: simple to use with that chip. Big community.
- Arduino esp8266 Websocket lib: apparently the fastest one based on the Arduino IDE.
- ws2812b i2s: it uses DMA to control the LEDs so no CPU.
- JS as UI: it works on every mobile device. Free.
- websockets: bidirectional realtime datatransfer. It works on every mobile device. Free.

Comment: Is there any reason not to simply send it the way it would usually be done? I.e with a binary chunk of data? `rgb(254,254,254)` is 16 bytes. `#FEFEFE` is 7 bytes and `■■■` is just 3 - each of these 3 representations specifies the exact same colour. In each case, the components are sent in the same order R, G, B. Binary data is not a problem for websockets - Here's a sample: https://plus.google.com/+FumitoshiUkai/posts/ERN6zYozENV

Comment: Why don't you just do it the way you're comfortable with first, and if you find that solution isn't performant (for example), look into an alternative solution?

Comment: @enhzflep nice. yeah thats something i was thinking of ... i just don't know how to handle the c++ part and convert it back.

Comment: @coco - just grab the bytes 1 by 1 and slap them into your pixels array. I.e `pixels[0].R = payload[0]; pixels[0].G = payload[1]; pixels[0].B = payload[2];` Each 3 bytes of the payload is a single pixel. :)

Comment: oh. so easy? hah ... At the server side i need to take the data as binary in this case... right? but how you get this ■■■? ba[i] = byteNumber == for example 255? or something.charCodeAt(i)

Comment: thats cool so basically 1000 leds are only 3000bytes...

Comment: @Andy i ask because it  isn't performant . i already tried with json , numberarrays .. but all that involves strings. and converting strings in a microcontroller is a big problem and memory usage.

Comment: @coco - Yep. Perhaps you don't realize, but `■` is ascii char #254. As binary, it's `11111110`, as decimal it's 254 and as hex it's 0xFE - these are merely _interpretations_ of the same data. `pixels[0].R = payload[0]` will take the binary data found in index 0 of the array and set it to the red component of your first pixel. These is no conversion needed..It really _is_ that simple! Yep, 1000 LEDs needs 3000 bytes - haven't played with Arduinos for a year or 2 and forget the speed of the i2c bus - i think it may be 100 or 150 kbps - 12,000 or 18,000 bytes a second - 4000-6000 LEDs worth.

Comment: @cocco The code that enhzflep gives _is_ for the server-side. Client-side you can use `String.fromCharacterCode(255, 0, 0)` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode).

Comment: @enhzflep maybe you should take your comments and put them into an answer :)

Comment: yeah the chip itself has something like 30000 bytes memory ... so it would be able to handle alot of leds.btw the best way would be to rewrite the ws2812b i2s lib to accept the whole binary data as it comes directly from websocket ... but thats another story.

Comment: it's not i2c it's i2s... that is used for audio conversion normally .. but developers used it to control leds

Comment: wiki "I2S is a communication protocol specifically designed to carry digital audio data. To quote from Wikipedia. I2S, also known as Inter-IC Sound, Integrated Interchip Sound, or IIS, is an electrical serial bus interface standard used for connecting digital audio devices together."

Comment: plus the esp8266 has also a cpu of 160mhz vs 16mhz of the arduino. so theoretically it should be alot faster

Comment: @cocco that's a lot of comments. If you feel they are relevant for your question, maybe you can edit them into the original text? That's easier for people who want to read this and maybe provide an answer of their own.

Comment: i get all zero's & sometimes 7 with    var a = new Uint8Array(size); a[0]= String.fromCharCode(255). also with Uint16Array & Uint32Array

Comment: String.fromCharCode(255)= ÿ in browser so prolly correct..

Comment: a[0]=String.fromCharCode(255,0,0); also does not work

Comment: @cocco don't trust what the debugger tells you. `a.charCodeAt(1)` gives you zero.

Comment: its a = new Uint8Array(size); a[0]=255,a[1]=0; the String.fromCharCode(255) part is not needed....but it does not work

Comment: i get the correct numbers printed out by the serial from the microcontroller but when i set pixels[0].R = payload[0]; pixels[0].G = payload[1]; pixels[0].B = payload[2]; the leds stay off

Comment: AAAAAAaaaaaaand i forgot to initialize the leds... it works

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-njWqbZT9G0 works great ... tested for a least 30 hours . no stutter, no data skip... whatever perfect.

Answer (score 0):

All the credit goes to **[enhzflep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630963/enhzflep)**

i just leave this here to remember how it works.

the `String.fromCharCode()` is not needed as it's a `Uint8Array` and so there is just to add the individual color range from 0 to 255

to send the binary data over websocket just pass the Uint8Array.**buffer**

**javascript**

create and send an array with 16 red pixels.

```
var pixels=16,
a=new Uint8Array(pixels*3),
l=pixels*1;
while(l--){
 a[l*3]=255;//red
 a[l*3+1]=0;//green
 a[l*3+2]=0;//blue
}
ws.send(a.buffer);
```

**c++**

set all the pixels from the recieved payload using the i2s [lib](https://github.com/JoDaNl/esp8266_ws2812_i2s) and the ws [lib](https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets)

```
case WStype_BIN:
 uint8_t l=NUM_LEDS*1;
 while(l--){
  pixels[l].R=payload[l*3];
  pixels[l].G=payload[l*3+1];
  pixels[l].B=payload[l*3+2];
 }
 ledstrip.show(pixels);
break;
```

The code is running over one hour now without a single stutter updating wirelessly 16 leds every 15ms.

With every other code/libs i had memory and other issues after max 15min.Using one led.

So... thx enhzflep.